# C++ performance: use getter in loop or save it to a variable first

Tags: c++, performance, loops

I was wondering if using a getter to get the same property over and over again in a loop has any performance hit. Should I save it to a variable first? Please see below examples:

Use getter directly:

```
for(int i=0; i<1000000; ++i) {
  print("Phone = %d\n", myobj->getCity("Foo")->getPhone(i);
}
```

**EDIT:**

What about the loop constraint?

```
for(int i=0; i<myobj->totalPhoneNum(); ++i) {...}
```

or

```
int totalPhoneNum = myobj->totalPhoneNum();
for(int i=0; i<totalPhoneNum; ++i) {...}
```

Comment: You should use getters in a loop only if the getter's parameters depend on some loop variable. In your case it is "constant" so that you should save it into a variable. It will be better-readable.

Comment: Just updated my question, what about loop constraint? I think one line is more readable and clean, but totalPhoneNum is a constant here. Which one is more preferable?

Comment: In case you missed my comment on the (now deleted) answer, the compiler can't optimize it unless it can prove that `totalPhoneNum()` is constant and has no side-effects. If that function is even slightly non-trivial, you're probably better off pulling it out manually.

Comment: I think in the second case the myobj->totalPhoneNum() can be used because it returns only a constant value.

Comment: @Mysticial: it should also proof that print(f?) doesn't change myobj, etc..

Comment: @user396672 Yes, that too! This is one of the reasons why I almost always prefer to do [loop-invariant code motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion) manually. There are simply too many corner cases that will prevent the compiler from doing it for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you should.  Regardless of whether it makes any difference on performance it's semantically clearer.  By saving it to a variable first you indicate that it's a loop invariant.

Comment: Assuming it actually is a loop invariant, and could not change during the loop.

Comment: @Jeff, what about the 2nd case in my question? Sounds like both ways do not have too much difference(?).

Comment: Same argument applies.  You don't want `myobj->totalPhoneNum()` to be evaluated each time around the loop because it's a loop invariant.   Pulling it out to a variable makes this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you modify it like this to **check for NULL**

```
City* city = myobj->getCity("Foo");
if(city != NULL)
{    
     for(int i=0; i<1000000; ++i) 
     {
       print("Phone = %d\n", city ->getPhone(i);
     }
}
```

unless you are not doing myobj->totalPhoneNum() in couple of places it is fine to call by this way